# IPv6 server not reachable in Amazon Ec2

Tags: windows, amazon-ec2, ipv6, xampp

I am working on a Apple iOS app, which uses the backend server running at Amazon EC2. Amazon EC2 VPC doesn't support IPv6 address by native. I couldn't make use of Amazon ELB support provided for EC2 classic platform, since my account uses VPC only

**Apple Announcement**

*At WWDC 2015 we announced the transition to IPv6-only network services in iOS 9. Starting June 1, 2016 all apps submitted to the App Store must support IPv6-only networking.*

**HE Tunnel Broker Service**

I have setup the tunnel. This is my IP6 Tunnel configuration. I'm able to ping and browse ipv6.google.com. I could also ping the IP6 Default gateway provided by HE tunnel broker service in EC2

**Tunnel adapter IP6Tunnel:**

```
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : ap-southeast-1.compute.internal
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft Direct Point-to-point Adapater
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   IPv6 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 2001:470:35:b37::2(Preferred)
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::e8e6:1ae2:d639:619b%14(Preferred)
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 2001:470:35:b37::1
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 172.31.0.2
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Disabled
```

**DNS records for my domain**

```
Name                     TTL    Class   Type         Data
ahlanapi.foodengine.in. 12634   IN      A           52.77.114.38
ahlanapi.foodengine.in. 299     IN      AAAA        2001:470:36:b37::2
```

I am able to access my website within EC2 and internet as well : http://ahlanapi.foodengine.in/ahlanapi/mumum/home

**Problem in IPv6 validation test**

When i perform the IPv6 test in http://ipv6-test.com/validate.php

It's not able to connect to my IPv6 webserver listening at

```
Listen 0.0.0.0:80
Listen [2001:470:35:b37::2]:80
```

[image]

What might be the problem? Please let me know if you need more information

Comment: Can the down voter explain what's wrong with this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is simple. You have a typo in your DNS record.

Your IPv6 address is `2001:470:35:b37::2`, but your AAAA record has `2001:470:36:b37::2`.

You may resolve the problem by correcting the AAAA record.

Comment: OMG, Jeez. That was the thing. facepalm !! Great find sir.

Comment: On Validating IPv6 testing using [ipv6-test.com](http://ipv6-test.com/validate.php) - IPv6 DNS server - This domain has no IPv6 DNS server, this may prevent some IPv6-only users from reaching it. Do you know about this?

Comment: @Keerthivasan Your domain's DNS servers don't support IPv6. They will be reachable by dual-stack clients, but IPv6-only clients will not be able to resolve your domain name. Your DNS provider must fix this, or if they will not do so, you will need a new DNS provider.

Comment: FWIW I believe `2001:470:35:b37::/64` is the link prefix assigned to the tunnel, and `2001:470:36:b37::/64` is the prefix routed through the tunnel intended to be used on the LAN.